# What is the case of trade-off in different Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta, stiffness

There are so many Runge-Kutta methods, including [Dormand-Prince](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method) 45, [Cash-Karp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash%E2%80%93Karp_method) 54, [Fehlberge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta%E2%80%93Fehlberg_method) 78.

Is there any comparison between them? E.g.

- What is each approach sacrificing?
- What is the general trade-off in different RK methods?
- Which approach is suitable for what model?
- How does Cash-Karp Method perform when we have a non-smooth solution?
- How does Dormand-Prince Method when we have a non-smooth solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There are so many Runge Kutta methods, including
>
> - Dormand-Prince 45
> - Cash-Karp 54
> - Fehlberge (sic) 78
>
> Is there any comparison between them?

Well, sure. Here are some traits to compare:

- Is the method implicit or explicit? (All of your examples are explicit RK methods.)
- What is the order of convergence? Are there any embedded error estimators? How many, and of what order(s)?
- How many stages does it have?
- How many function evaluations are required? For implicit methods, how many linear solves are involved?
- What is the stability region? Is it A-stable? L-stable?

My relatively simplistic understanding of these methods is that:

- Dormand-Prince 4(5) is a 4th-order method with a 5th-order error estimator designed to minimize the error in the 5th-order solution, which is preferable when using the 5th-order solution to continue the integration
- Fehlberg methods are supposed to minimize the error in the lower-order solution (in your case, the 7th-order solution); in general, Dormand-Prince methods of the same order should perform better
- I've heard of the Cash-Karp discretization, but I haven't across a source that claims any sort of advantage or disadvantage compared with the Dormand-Prince methods

> What is each approach sacrificing?
>
> What is the general trade-off in different RK methods?

You should look at (or construct!) work-precision diagrams for the problems and integrators you're interested in investigating. Hairer and Wanner have some examples.

> Which approach is suitable for what model?

Again, you should look at work-precision diagrams. To a very coarse approximation, you want explicit Runge-Kutta methods for non-stiff problems (assuming, that is, you want to use a Runge-Kutta method), and for stiff problems, you're likely to want an implicit Runge-Kutta method. Methods with a higher order of accuracy per time step are likely to perform better at stricter error tolerances than methods with a lower order of accuracy. However, the best approach is (very) problem-dependent.

Comment: I think before looking at complete implicit Runge-Kutta methods, give the linear-implicit ones, like the Rosenbrock schemes a try, because they are easier to implement and need only one Jacobian of your ODE function.

Comment: @Grisu: Agreed. The question is so broad, I didn't even bother to get into DIRK, SDIRK, Rosenbrock, Rosenbrock-W, etc.

Comment: You can check some of these properties for a lot of common methods at http://ketch.github.io/numipedia/.  Let me know if your favorite method or property is not there.

Comment: In contrast to Fehlberg's methods, where the higher order method is indeed optimized as error estimator for the lower order method, the Dormand-Prince methods are optimized and used as extrapolation methods, so dopri 5 is a 5(4) method